# How to track Drupal user login-logout session length and registration activities?

Tags: users

Is there any hook_function/code in Drupal where I can track user activity, like:

1. User core logged in time / or third party login
2. User log out time
3. Login-Logout session length (active time)
4. registration submit core or / third party submit.

Please share event for these activity.

Comment: Try hook_user_login and hook_user_logout for 1 and 2

Comment: thanks, but same will work if I logged in using 3rd party apps like fb/G+

Comment: I think it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For standard login, and 3rd-party login modules that are properly integrated with core, you can use:

- [`hook_user_login()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7.x)
- [`hook_user_logout()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_logout/7.x)
- [`hook_user_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7.x)

For 3rd-party login modules that aren't properly integrated with core (i.e. don't fire those hooks), you'll need to approach each on a case-by-case basis, and find out what hooks they provide.

You could measure the duration of the session in `hook_user_logout`, by checking the account object's `login` property against the current time -  there's no hook for such a thing as it's not an event, just a value which needs some context to give it meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Event log](https://www.drupal.org/project/event_log) module (a module also consists of "Drupal code", right?). Some details about it, from its project page:

> This module logs specific events. The events are saved in the database and can be viewed on the page admin/reports/events. Furthermore, a views integration is provided in which you can relate for instance a node to its events. You could use this to display the total number of views, or the number of times that the node has been modified and by which users.
>
> Currently, the following events are supported:
>
> - User authentication (login/logout/request password)
> - Node operations (CRUD)
> - User operations (CRUD)
> - Menu operations (custom menu's and menu items CUD operations)
> - Taxonomy operations (vocabulary and term CUD operations)
>
> The event log can be easily extended with custom events. For more information please have a look at the API documentation and the available sub modules.

You are probably going to be interested in these specific events and facilities of it:

- User authentication.
- User operations (CRUD).
- ... log can be easily extended with custom events.
- Views integration.
- API documentation.
- The available sub modules.